# Weak convergence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ implies weak convergente in $H^1(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in the sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ converging weakly to some $u \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. How can I prove that some subsequence converges to the same limite in $H^1(B)$, where $B$ is an open ball ?  I have tried using the fallowing result from Evans, 2010, page 268:

Theorem: Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Select a bounded open set $V$ such that $U \subset \subset V$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator
$$
E : H^1(U) \rightarrow H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) 
$$
such that for each $u \in H^1(U)$:
i) E(u) = u, a.e. in $U$,
ii) Eu has support within $V$,
and
iii) Exists a constant $C > 0$ such that
$$
||E(u)||_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq C ||u||_{H^1(U)}.
$$

Comment: I don't think you need something so fancy. The restriction operator $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)\to H^1(B)$ is continuous and linear, and therefore sends weakly convergent sequences to weakly convergent sequences. Alternatively, notice that you're *restricting* the class of test functions with which to pair the sequence, so the weak convergence is immediate.

Comment: To add to @Jose27’s comment, the theorem you quote from Evan’s is going to wrong way - it is extending Sobolev functions from $B$ (say) to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much !